# How cal function inside a function in the Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

How cal function inside a function in the Controller in Laravel

I am getting error which is below given

```
message: "Call to undefined function createThumb()"
```

I think the error is while calling createThumb in the jquery_register function

Here is my Route:

```
Route::post('up', 'UploadController@jquery_register');
```

Here is my View :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Image upload and generate thumbnail using ajax in PHP</title>
<link href="assets/temp/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/temp/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/temp/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('change', '#image_upload_file', function () {
var progressBar = $('.progressBar'), bar = $('.progressBar .bar'), percent = $('.progressBar .percent');

$('#image_upload_form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        progressBar.fadeIn();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function(html, statusText, xhr, $form) {       
        obj = $.parseJSON(html);    
        if(obj.status){     
            var percentVal = '100%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
            $("#imgArea>img").prop('src',obj.image_medium);         
        }else{

      alert(obj.error);
        }
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        progressBar.fadeOut();          
    }   
}).submit();        

});
</script>
</head>

<body>



<br>


<div id="imgContainer">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="up" method="post" name="image_upload_form" id="image_upload_form">
    <div id="imgArea"><img src="assets/temp/img/default.jpg">
      <div class="progressBar">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="percent">0%</div>
      </div>
      <div id="imgChange"><span>Change Photo</span>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="image_upload_file" id="image_upload_file">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Controller :

```
<?php

class UploadController extends BaseController {

    //start of jquery register



    public function jquery_register()
    {   

ini_set("memory_limit", "99M");
ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
define('IMAGE_SMALL_DIR', '');
define('IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE', 50);
define('IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR', '');
define('IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE', 250);

if(isset($_FILES['image_upload_file'])){
    $output['status']=FALSE;
    set_time_limit(0);
    $allowedImageType = array("image/gif",   "image/jpeg",   "image/pjpeg",   "image/png",   "image/x-png"  );

    if ($_FILES['image_upload_file']["error"] > 0) {
        $output['error']= "Error in File";
    }
    elseif (!in_array($_FILES['image_upload_file']["type"], $allowedImageType)) {
        $output['error']= "You can only upload JPG, PNG and GIF file";
    }
    elseif (round($_FILES['image_upload_file']["size"] / 1024) > 4096) {
        $output['error']= "You can upload file size up to 4 MB";
    } else {
        /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - start*/
        /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - end*/
        $path[0] = $_FILES['image_upload_file']['tmp_name'];
        $file = pathinfo($_FILES['image_upload_file']['name']);
        $fileType = $file["extension"];
        $desiredExt='jpg';
        $fileNameNew = rand(333, 999) . time() . ".$desiredExt";
        $path[1] = IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR . $fileNameNew;
        $path[2] = IMAGE_SMALL_DIR . $fileNameNew;


        $output['status']=TRUE;
                $output['image_medium']= $path[1];

        if (createThumb($path[0], $path[1], $fileType, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE,IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE)) {

            if (createThumb($path[1], $path[2],"$desiredExt", IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE, IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE,IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE)) {
                $output['status']=TRUE;
                $output['image_medium']= $path[1];
                $output['image_small']= $path[2];
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}





        }


    public  function createThumb($path1, $path2, $file_type, $new_w, $new_h, $squareSize = '')
{

    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = FALSE;

    if (preg_match("/jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG/", $file_type)) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/png|PNG/", $file_type)) {

        if (!$source_image = @imagecreatefrompng($path1)) {
            $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
        }
    }
    elseif (preg_match("/gif|GIF/", $file_type)) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($path1);
    }       
    if ($source_image == FALSE) {
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path1);
    }

    $orig_w = imageSX($source_image);
    $orig_h = imageSY($source_image);

    if ($orig_w < $new_w && $orig_h < $new_h) {
        $desired_width = $orig_w;
        $desired_height = $orig_h;
    } else {
        $scale = min($new_w / $orig_w, $new_h / $orig_h);
        $desired_width = ceil($scale * $orig_w);
        $desired_height = ceil($scale * $orig_h);
    }

    if ($squareSize != '') {
        $desired_width = $desired_height = $squareSize;
    }

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);
    // for PNG background white----------->
    $kek = imagecolorallocate($virtual_image, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($virtual_image, 0, 0, $kek);

    if ($squareSize == '') {
        /* copy source image at a resized size */
        imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
    } else {
        $wm = $orig_w / $squareSize;
        $hm = $orig_h / $squareSize;
        $h_height = $squareSize / 2;
        $w_height = $squareSize / 2;

        if ($orig_w > $orig_h) {
            $adjusted_width = $orig_w / $hm;
            $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
            $int_width = $half_width - $w_height;
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, -$int_width, 0, 0, 0, $adjusted_width, $squareSize, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        }

        elseif (($orig_w <= $orig_h)) {
            $adjusted_height = $orig_h / $wm;
            $half_height = $adjusted_height / 2;
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0,0, 0, 0, $squareSize, $adjusted_height, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        } else {
            imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $squareSize, $squareSize, $orig_w, $orig_h);
        }
    }

    if (@imagejpeg($virtual_image, $path2, 90)) {
        imagedestroy($virtual_image);
        imagedestroy($source_image);
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}   

    }  // end of the controller
```

What is the mistake i am doing in the code.

Note : Actually the code is taken from raw php for the sake of upload and display the image.

Comment: Use $this->createThumb(...

Comment: at here -- > if (createThumb($p,... ?

Comment: Yeah, to call methods inside the same class from a method inside it, you should use $this->

Comment: lol i thought it was a quick ans so i gave it here. anyway i will write an answer wait for it and mark it :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a method inside the same class, you should use $this variable.

```
class Test {
     public function main() {
         bee(); // won't work as this will try to find the method "bee" in \ namespace
         $q = strpos("test", "e"); // will work as "strpos" method is in the \ namespace
         $this->bee(); // will work as "bee" method is present in the same class
         $q = $this->strpos("test", "e"); // will fail as "strpos" method does not exist in class
     }

     public function ae(){
         echo "a";
     }

     public function bee(){
          echo "b";
     }
}
```

In your case, the solution is just to replace "createThumb(" with:

```
$this->createThumb(
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: lol before asking questions like this you should study php basics properly. ofcourse people are going to downvote if you come here to ask for help on trivial mistakes you make..

Comment: anyway just because you upvoted i'll upvote you (mods pls spare me :p)

Comment: thanks, shall delete comments from question and answer, as it makes a sense